# UWP: How to get byte[] from AudioFrame and then play it?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to get the buffer from the AudioFrame and convert it to byte array, send over the network, and than play it. I am able to transfer the bytes no problem, but when I try to play it i only get static. I tested it and I know, that my microphoone works ok.

Here is my code,

**MyRecorder.cs**

```
private void OnQuantumReady(AudioGraph sender, object data)
    {
        if (IsRecording)
        {
            AudioFrame frame = outputFrameNode.GetFrame();

            ProcessFrameOutput(frame);                
        }            
    }

    unsafe private void ProcessFrameOutput(AudioFrame frame)
    {

        using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
        {
            Byte[] audioBytes = new byte[buffer.Length];

            using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
            {
                byte* dataInBytes;
                uint capacityInBytes;

                // Get the buffer from the AudioFrame
                ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);

                fixed (byte* buf = audioBytes)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                    {
                        buf[i] = dataInBytes[i];
                    }
                }                                        
            }

            DataRecorded?.Invoke(bytesToSend.Take(bufferSize).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyPlayer.cs**

```
public void PlayData(Byte[] datas)
    {            
        AudioFrame frame = new AudioFrame((uint)datas.Length);

        using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
        {

            using (Windows.Foundation.IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* dataInBytes;
                    uint capacityInBytes;

                    // Get the buffer from the AudioFrame
                    ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);


                    fixed (byte* buf = datas)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dataInBytes[i] = buf[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        framesToPlay.Add(frame);
    }


    private void OnQuantumStarted(AudioGraph sender, object data)
    {
        if(framesToPlay.Any())
        {
            AudioFrame frame = framesToPlay.FirstOrDefault();
            inputFrameNode.AddFrame(frame);
            framesToPlay.Remove(frame);
        }
    }
```

In both cases I use AudioGraphs with identical encoding properties.

I based my solution on official UWP samples(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) and this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/pull/615

**EDIT:**
I found where the issue is (still dont know how to fix it). I tried using the frame from GetFrame() and passing it directly into AudioInputFrameNode and it is just static. So problem lies here:

```
AudioFrame frame = outputFrameNode.GetFrame();
```

Comment: `Byte*` could be used to represent a byte array, you could convert it to the `byte[]` format by using `Marshal.Copy Method ()`.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I tried that but it does not work for me (and idk why).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `AudioDeviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection`
method to wire the input and output nodes together before starting the audio graph:

```
//outputFrameNode = yourAudioGraph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
yourInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(outputFrameNode);
```

Comment: Hey dex, it might help if you also stated *why* this is necessary. Can you update your answer?